# Failed to fetch log file from worker while running docker operator

Tags: docker, airflow

Im trying to run simple DAG with docker-operator on airflow. Here is my DAG:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator

default_args = {
'owner'                 : 'airflow',
'description'           : 'Use of the DockerOperator',
'depend_on_past'        : False,
'start_date'            : datetime(2018, 1, 3),
'email_on_failure'      : False,
'email_on_retry'        : False,
'retries'               : 1,
'retry_delay'           : timedelta(minutes=5)
}
with DAG('docker_dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="* * * * *", catchup=False) as dag:
    t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_current_date',
    bash_command='date'
    )
    t2 = DockerOperator(
    task_id='docker_command',
    image='centos:latest',
    api_version='auto',
    auto_remove=True,
    command="/bin/sleep 30",
    docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
    network_mode="bridge"
    )
    t3 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_hello',
    bash_command='echo "hello world"'
    )
t1 >> t2 >> t3
```

The first task runs correct, but with docker-task i got this error:

```
*** Log file does not exist: ./logs/docker_dag/docker_command/2022-08-12T14:40:00+00:00/2.log
*** Fetching from: http://airflow_docker_host:8793/log/docker_dag/docker_command/2022-08-12T14:40:00+00:00/2.log
*** !!!! Please make sure that all your Airflow components (e.g. schedulers, webservers and workers) have the same 'secret_key' configured in 'webserver' section !!!!!
****** See more at https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#secret-key
****** Failed to fetch log file from worker. 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: http://airflow_docker_host:8793/log/docker_dag/docker_command/2022-08-12T14:40:00+00:00/2.log
For more information check: https://httpstatuses.com/403
```

I have only one server where webserver, scheduler, and docker-daemon run. I have default SequentialExecutor

Docker-configuration:

```
[airflow@airflow_docker_host .docker]$ cat config.json 
{ 
  "proxies":
    { 
      "default": 
        { 
          "httpProxy": "http://172.20.127.125:8080", 
          "httpsProxy": "https://172.20.127.125:8080", 
          "noProxy": "*.<domain>,127.0.0.0/8" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: can you add your docker configuration?

Comment: what is your airflow version?

Comment: @AshkanGolehPour my airflow version is 2.2.3